how should I solve 403 forbidden [104.17.253.239 80] error in kali linux 2024?
I just installed kali Linux 2024.2, when I try to update and upgrade my kali with this command: sudo apt update / sudo apt upgrade -y I get this error:
[sudo] password for mo:
Err:1 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 104.17.253.239 80]
Error: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 104.17.253.239 80]
Error: The repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease' is not signed.
Notice: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
Notice: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
Notice: Repository 'Kali Linux' changed its 'firmware component' value from 'non-free' to 'non-free-firmware'
Notice: More information about this can be found online at: https://www.kali.org/blog/non-free-firmware-transition/

I tried https instead of http in my sources list file but the issue persists, would you please help me to solve this issue?

Are you using the correct repository? https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/

here is my sources.list file content: # See https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
Additional line for source packages
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free non-free-firmware / what should I do ?

I tried to modify the file /etc/apt/sources.list with source packages repository address including https instead of http and it worked!
This is my file content:
#See https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/
deb https://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free non-free-firmware

#Additional line for source packages
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free non-free-firmware


I do this but my problem still persist.
